# SQL Join with multiple conditions for one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my situation, I've **two tables**, a table with all institutions profile and a table which represents material studied by each of these institutions.

In a search, **I want to look for institution's name which studied specifics type of material**. So it's possible to look for institution which studied "Wood" and "Metal", just "Metal" etc...

I've tried the following query :

```
    SELECT p.name
    FROM q1_institution_profiles p
    INNER JOIN q9_materials_studied_by_institution pf 
    ON pf.id_institution = p.id_institution
    WHERE pf.id_material_studied = 10 AND pf.id_material_studied = 8
```

However result is empty because there is a problem when I have multiple conditions (here id_material_studied must be equal 8 and 10).

Is there a way to achieve this properly or do I have to do on join for each criteria ?

Thank you in advance for answer

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding this correctly, but it seems like changing the AND in your where statement to an OR should give you what you want.

Comment: WHERE (pf.id_material_studied = 10 OR pf.id_material_studied = 8)

Comment: No it doesn't work.. because I have to fullfill the two conditions and with a "OR" it's not the case. It selects all which are equal to 8 and all which are equal to 10, not only the ones which are equal to 8 and 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM q1_institution_profiles p INNER JOIN
     q9_materials_studied_by_institution pf 
     ON pf.id_institution = p.id_institution
WHERE pf.id_material_studied IN (8, 10)
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pf.id_material_studied) = 2;
```

That is, get names where there are rows with each of the two values.

The `WHERE` clause selects only materials 8 and 10.  The `GROUP BY` then groups these by `p.name`.  The question is:  Does a single name have *both* these materials?  Well, that is what `count(distinct)` does.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly ! But, if you have the times, can you explain me the logic of this query ?